# Receive data with UDP socket in VS2013

Tags: c, sockets, udp, bind

I wanted to receive an `*.xml` data by port `3702`.

So I made a example Server. And sended data by three port `1500,2500,3702`.(Edit the PORT in line 43)

It worked and printed data correctly from port 1500,2500.
But when I set the PORT to 3702.

it returned me a error:`**Bind failed with error code :10048**`

I found that maybe it existed other Client IP were sending data by PORT 3702 in my LAN.
How can I fix it?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<winsock2.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library

#define BUFLEN 8192  //Max length of buffer
#define PORT 3702   //The port on which to listen for incoming data

int main()
{
    SOCKET s;
    struct sockaddr_in server, si_other;
    int slen, recv_len;
    char buf[BUFLEN];
    WSADATA wsa;

    slen = sizeof(si_other);

    //Initialise winsock
    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Initialised.\n");

    //Create a socket
    if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket : %d", WSAGetLastError());
    }
    printf("Socket created.\n");

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    //Bind
    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Bind failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    puts("Bind done");

    //keep listening for data
    while (1)
    {
        printf("Waiting for data...");
        fflush(stdout);

        //clear the buffer by filling null, it might have previously received data
        memset(buf, '\0', BUFLEN);

        //try to receive some data, this is a blocking call
        if ((recv_len = recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen)) ==     SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("recvfrom() failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
            //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        //print details of the client/peer and the data received
        printf("Received packet from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(si_other.sin_addr), ntohs(si_other.sin_port));
        printf("Data: %s\n", buf);

        //now reply the client with the same data

    }

    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why the hell do you winsock on Linux !? That's the windows socket library. Use socket.h instead

Comment: Sorry it wrong.It's in Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to  **Address already in use**.

Typically, only one usage of each socket address (protocol/IP address/port) is permitted. This error occurs if an application attempts to [bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737550(v=vs.85).aspx) a socket to an IP address/port that has already been used for an existing socket, or a socket that was not closed properly, or one that is still in the process of closing. For server applications that need to `bind` multiple sockets to the same port number, consider using [setsockopt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476(v=vs.85).aspx) (`SO_REUSEADDR`).

Client applications usually need not call bind at all - [connect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737625(v=vs.85).aspx) chooses an unused port automatically. When bind is called with a wildcard address (involving `ADDR_ANY`), a `WSAEADDRINUSE` error could be delayed until the specific address is committed. This could happen with a call to another function later, including `connect`, [listen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms739168(v=vs.85).aspx), [WSAConnect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741559(v=vs.85).aspx), or [WSAJoinLeaf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741628(v=vs.85).aspx).